# Cannot upload media files to wordpress website

Tags: wordpress, google-cloud-platform

I have created a new project and deployment for my WordPress website. I followed each step of the Google guided tutorial and have come across 2 issues:

1. Error message on deployment page (see attachment) - how do I resolve the Runtime Config issue? I have only followed the guide [here](https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/product/click-to-deploy-images/wordpress?tutorial=marketplace_wordpress&_ga=2.259459592.384252050.1689038329-1897534514.1686802847&_gac=1.21114569.1689038344.CjwKCAjw2K6lBhBXEiwA5RjtCedkmy2_RRc1RlLSnqHKHiHzmPWTAuIbtC9MqswU17aLKoRzFnH4VhoC6PsQAvD_BwE&organizationId=55991901269)
   [deployment issue image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hXwc7.png)
2. I cannot upload any media files through my WordPress website, when I try all I get is a grey box - Is there an API that I may have not enabled? I've searched your documentation and have not found anything as of yet.
   [media file upload issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uraCV.png)

I have attached screenshots of the issues.

I'm pretty new to the Google Cloud Platform so any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Tried contacting support who would not help as they said it's out of their scope

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your first problem, WordPress Click to Deploy, the error message cannot be resolved. This is because the product is not updated. As a beta product, there is no support. Your option is to continue with the product as is or use the traditional method of creating a VM, installing Apache, PHP, and MySQL. If you are just learning, the Click to Deploy is fine. You can update the product yourself easily.

Your second problem is very common. Most install methods use the default PHP configuration settings, so knowing the following will help you with many similar problems.

To change the maximum file upload size, you must change a few settings for the PHP version Apache is using. A server can have multiple PHP installations so you must modify the correct installation. Almost all servers running Apache have at least two versions installed.

To determine which php.ini your server is using, create a PHP page:

```
<?php
phpinfo();
```

Load that page into a browser. Review the following section:

[image]

Notice two items from the screenshot:

- The version of PHP
- The location of the Configuration File (php.ini) Path

**Example for PHP 7.4 FPM**

Edit `/etc/php/7.4/fpm/php.ini`

- Change `upload_max_filesize = 2M` to the required size
- Change `post_max_size = 8M` to the required size
- Reboot the server. Depending on the Apache/PHP configuration, restarting Apache will not always reload the PHP settings (e.g. PHP FPM).